# NotificationCenter addObserver() issue

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to enable segue into a specific view upon opening a local notification by using `NotificationCenter.addObserver(...)`

My code is

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(LocalNotificationViewController.test), name: ???, object: nil)
}
```

With `test` method to perform the segue to `ViewController` with identifier `NotificationView` which I'm not sure what to put...

```
@objc func SomeNotificationAct(notification: NSNotification){
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NotificationView", sender: self)
    }
}
```

My main question is how do I know the name of my local notification to put into the `NotificationCenter.addObserver(...)` method?

Comment: Local notifications are different then Notification Center

Comment: How do u suggest I do this then?

Comment: you may do stuff in func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) method.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create extension for Notification name like,

```
extension Notification.Name {

     static let hello1 = Notification.Name("HelloNotifcationName")
     static let hello2 = Notification.Name("HelloNotifcationName2")

}
```

and use it like this,

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setToHelloName1(notification:)), name: .hello1, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setToHelloName2(notfication:)), name: .hello2, object: nil)
```

You can find further reference or tutorial,[here](https://medium.com/@JoyceMatos/using-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift-eb70cf0b60fc)